# Regex Help (PHP) in finding and selecting characters between 2 strings

Tags: php, regex

i need help with an Reg. Ex. i have a long text with many whitespaces and new lines, i need to find and select ALL between 2 strings.
example:

```
iojge test rgej <foo>
ferfe 098n34hjlrej
fefe <end
```

i want to find all between test and end:

```
 rgej <foo>
ferfe 098n34hjlrej
fefe <
```

how can i do this?

Comment: So, `test` and `end` can never be a part of the text you're trying to match? What if the string looks like: `"test testing ending end"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
preg_match("/test(.*?)end/s", $yourString, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: The `m` flag will cause `$` to match the end of the line and `^` match the start of a line: it will *not* let the DOT meta character match line breaks. This is done with the `s` flag.

Comment: This will capture `test` and `end`, which doesn't comply with the OP's sample.

Comment: @Daniel Vandersluis, Check $matches[1]

Comment: @Colin yeah I know that but the OP might not ;)

Comment: Yeah, and it is pretty clear that the desired match resides at index 1 after looking at the output `print_r($matches);` produces. I like this one better than the look-around suggestion. The readability of this answer is much better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use two [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and the `/s` (single line) [modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html), which makes the [dot](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) match newlines, to look for everything between your two words:

```
/(?<=test).*(?=end)/s
```

To explain:

```
(?<=    # open a positive lookbehind
  test  # match 'test'
)       # close the lookbehind
.*      # match as many characters as possible (including newlines because of the \s modifier)
(?=     # open a positive lookahead
 end    # match 'end'
)       # close the lookahead
```

The lookarounds will let you assert that the pattern must be anchored by your two words, but since lookarounds are not capturing, only everything between the words will be returned by `preg_match`. A lookbehind looks *behind* the current position to see if the assertion passes; a lookahead looks *after* the current position.

Since regular expressions are [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) by default, the `.*` will match as much as it can (so if the ending word appears multiple times, it will match until the last one). If you want to match only until the first time it encounters `end`, you can make the `.*` [lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) (in other words, it'll match as *little* as possible that still satisfies the pattern) by changing it to `.*?` (ie. `/(?<=test).*?(?=end)/s`).

Comment: To be on the safe side, I'd make it a reluctant DOT-STAR.

Comment: @Bart it depends on what the OP wants to capture. I've updated my answer to discuss that though.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can also do:

```
$arr1 = explode("test",$input);
$arr2 = explode("end",$arr1[1]);
$result = $arr2[0];
```

Comment: What if there is no `test` in `$input`?

Comment: @Gumbo: In that case the `$result` will be empty string. But I think there will be warnings of some invalid index. So you are right there needs to be some error checking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed delimiters, you don’t need regular expressions:

```
$str = 'iojge test rgej <foo>
ferfe 098n34hjlrej
fefe <end';
$start = 'test';
$end = 'end';
if (($startPos = strpos($str, $start)) !== false && ($endPos = strpos($str, $end, $startPos+=strlen($start))) !== false) {
    // match found
    $match = substr($str, $startPos, $endPos-$startPos);
}
```